# Can Top quarks change their spin direction?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-spin, quarks, weak-interaction

Since we know there are right handed quarks, and that the Weak Force does not interact with Right Handed particles, if a quark cannot change its spin direction, how does the Top quark decay?

If the Top quark cannot change its direction of spin, and the Weak Force will not interact, shouldn't the Top should have time to actually form a meson?

Oscillation between spin directions would make sense from a decay standpoint...  I am just not sure it is functionally possible.

Answer (score 1):

The correlation between chirality and spin appears at high momentum. (This is shown nicely in Pekín & Schroeder.) A particle in its rest frame is always equal parts left- and right-chiral. Decay lifetimes are computed from the rest frame.

So for instance, the decay $\pi^+\to\mu^+\nu_\mu$ is preferred over the more energetic $\pi^+\to\mathrm e^+\nu_\mathrm e$, because the phase space for a left-chiral neutrino and a right-chiral positron to add up to spin zero is much smaller than for the non-relativistic $\mu$.  But you can’t, say, change the lifetime of an ultra-relativistic antimuon beam by flipping the spins so the antimuons are left-handed in your reference frame.